# How can I reduce a numpy array into bins with a max value per bin?

Tags: python, numpy

My array looks like: `(212960,)`

I want to split that up into `625` bins of equal length. Since 212960 / 625 isn't an integer, I don't really care about the remaining pieces.

For each bin, I want to fill it with whatever the max value is.

I feel like there's a `.reshape` needed, just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do (and yes, with `reshape`):

```
# sample data
a = np.arange(212960)

bins = 625

max_size = (len(a)//bins) * bins

new_arr = a[:max_size].reshape(bins, -1).max(1)
```

Comment: Looks great - can you explain what the `-1` does?

Comment: That means the other dimension will be calculated from the input shape and the first dimension.